# Background grey out not applied to navbar-collapse section

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and jQuery on my page and on click of button greying out entire window with jQuery code given below but grey out not applied to navbar-collapse with id as "collapse" as other section on page are greyed out shown in image attached....Given below html section that is not greyed out, complete html and corresponding jQuery with image attached!         Help to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!![image: Image with background grey out not applied for navbar]

```
    **jQuery**
        $('#background').css({  "display": "block", opacity: 0.7,"width":$(document).width(),
        "height":$(document).height()}).fadeIn("slow");
        $('#overlay').center();
        $('#overlay').show();

    **HTML Section not Greyed Out**
    <div class="row">
            <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="text-decoration: none">Click on Button to see options</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>
                        <a href="#/hme" id="hme" class="first-item" ng-click='showHome=false;showMortagage=false'>Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                        <a href="#/homeloans" ng-click="showHome=true;showMortagage=false" id="homeloans">Home Loans</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                        <a href="#/mortagage" id="mortagage" ng-click="showMortagage=true;showHome=false">Mortagage Loans</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                        <a href="#/personal" id="personal" ng-click="showHome=false;showMortagage=false">Personal Loans</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                        <a href="#/business" id="business" ng-click="showHome=false;showMortagage=false">Business Loans</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                        <a href="#/others" id="others" ng-click="showHome=false;showMortagage=false">Other Loans</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                        <a href="#/aboutus" id="aboutus" ng-click="showHome=false;showMortagage=false">About Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                        <a href="#/contactus" class="last-item" id="contactus" ng-click="showHome=false;showMortagage=false">Contact Us</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    **Complete HTML**
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Loan Site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/specific.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body ng-app="demoApp">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="text-decoration: none">Click on Button to see options</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                    <a href="#/hme" id="hme" class="first-item" ng-click='showHome=false;showMortagage=false'>Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#/homeloans" ng-click="showHome=true;showMortagage=false" id="homeloans">Home Loans</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#/mortagage" id="mortagage" ng-click="showMortagage=true;showHome=false">Mortagage Loans</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#/personal" id="personal" ng-click="showHome=false;showMortagage=false">Personal Loans</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#/business" id="business" ng-click="showHome=false;showMortagage=false">Business Loans</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#/others" id="others" ng-click="showHome=false;showMortagage=false">Other Loans</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#/aboutus" id="aboutus" ng-click="showHome=false;showMortagage=false">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#/contactus" class="last-item" id="contactus" ng-click="showHome=false;showMortagage=false">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="moduletable">
                <h3>EMI Calculator</h3>
                <div ng-controller="EmiCtrl" class="emi">
                    <form method="post" name="loanForm" id="loanForm">
                        <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                 Loan Amount:<br/>
                                <span class="clr" ng-show="loanForm.loan.$error.required">required</span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="number" name="loan" id="loan" ng-model="user.loan" required>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                 Tenure(Months):<br/>
                                <span class="clr" ng-show="loanForm.months.$error.required">required</span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="number" name="months" id="months" ng-model="user.months" required>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                 Int Rate:<br/>
                                <span class="clr" ng-show="loanForm.rate.$error.required">required</span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="number" name="rate" id="rate" ng-model="user.rate" required>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                 EMI:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="pay" id="pay" size="8" ng-model="user.pay">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding:20px;">
                                <div id="overlay">
                                    <a href="#" id="cls" style="font: '20px bold'" 
                                    onclick="$('#background').fadeOut('slow');$('#overlay').hide();">
                                    <img src="img/close.gif" style="position: absolute;top: 0px;right: 0px;"/>
                                    </a>
                                    <div style="border: 2px solid;margin: 0;padding: 0;text-align: center">
                                        <div style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 20px;">
                                            <span>EMI Amortization Chart</span><span></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="text-align: left;padding-left:180px">
                                            <span>Loan Amount:</span><span id="loanamt"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="text-align: left;padding-left:180px">
                                            <span>Tenor:</span><span id="monthtnr"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="text-align: left;padding-left:180px">
                                            <span>Int Rate:</span><span id="intrt"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="text-align: left;padding-left:180px">
                                            <span>EMI:</span><span id="emi"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <br/><br/>
                                    <div id="emitbl">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" id "btncalculate" e" name="btncalculate" onclick='toggleModal()' ng-disabled="loanForm.$invalid">Calculate</button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="button" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" ng-click="reset()">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
<!--Content for alert box -->
<div id="box">
        <a href="#" id="cls" style="font: '20px bold'" 
        onclick="$('#background').fadeOut('slow');$('#large').fadeOut('slow');$('#box').hide();$('#screen').hide();">
            <img src="img/close.gif" style="position: absolute;top: 0px;right: 0px;"/>
        </a>
        <div id="response"></div>
</div>
<div id="screen"></div>
<!--Content for alert box -->
            <div id="moduletable" style="margin-top:15px;margin-bottom: 10px">
                <h3>Apply For Loans</h3>
                <div>
                    <form method="post" id="adminForm" name="adminForm" ng-controller="ClearCtrl">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4" id="txt">
                                <div>Loan Type</div>
                                <div class="clr" ng-show="adminForm.loan_type.$error.required">required</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <select name="loan_type" id="loan_type" ng-model="user.loan_type" ng-init="user.loan_type='Please Select'" required>
                                    <option value="Please Select">Please Select</option>
                                    <option value="Home Loan">Home Loan</option>
                                    <option value="Mortgage Loan">Mortgage Loan</option>
                                    <option value="Personal Loan">Personal Loan</option>
                                    <option value="Business Loan">Business Loan</option>
                                    <option value="Other Loan">Other Loan</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="clear:both; height:10px;">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4" id="txt">
                                <div>Name</div>
                                <div class="clr" ng-show="adminForm.nme.$error.required">required</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <input type="text" name="nme" id="nme" class="textbox" ng-model="user.nme" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="clear:both; height:10px;">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4" id="txt">
                                <div>Mobile No</div>
                                <div class="clr" ng-show="adminForm.phone_no.$error.required">required</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <input type="number" name="phone_no" id="phone_no" maxlength="10" class="textbox" ng-model="user.phone_no" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="clear:both; height:10px;">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4" id="txt">
                                <div>E-mail ID</div>
                                <div class="clr" ng-show="adminForm.email_id.$invalid">required</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <input type="email" name="email_id" id="email_id" maxlength="35" class="email" ng-model="user.email_id" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="clear:both; height:10px;">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4" id="txt">
                                <div>Company</div>
                                <div class="clr" ng-show="adminForm.company.$error.required">required</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <input type="text" name="company" id="company" class="textbox" ng-model="user.company" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="clear:both; height:10px;">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4" id="txt">
                                <div>Occupation</div>
                                <div class="clr" ng-show="adminForm.Occupation.$error.required">required</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-7">
                                <select name="Occupation" id="Occupation" ng-model="user.Occupation" ng-init="user.Occupation='Please Select'" required>
                                    <option value="Please Select">Please Select</option>
                                    <option value="Salaried">Salaried</option>
                                    <option value="Self employed-Proprietor">Self employed-Proprietor</option>
                                    <option value="Self employed-partnership">Self employed-partnership</option>
                                    <option value="Self employed-Pvt Ltd">Self employed-Pvt Ltd</option>
                                    <option value="Self employed-Ltd">Self employed-Ltd</option>
                                    <option value="Others">Others</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="clear:both; height:10px;">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4" id="txt">
                                <div>Netincome (PM)</div>
                                <div class="clr" ng-show="adminForm.netincom.$error.required">required</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <input type="number" name="netincom" id="netincom" maxlength="500" class="editbox" ng-model="user.netincom" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="clear:both; height:10px;">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4" id="txt">
                                <div>City</div>
                                <div class="clr" ng-show="adminForm.City.$error.required">required</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <select name="City" id="City" ng-model="user.City" ng-init="user.City='Please Select'" required>
                                    <option value="Please Select">Please Select</option>
                                    <option value="Hyderabad">Hyderabad</option>
                                    <option value="Visakhapatnam">Visakhapatnam</option>
                                    <option value="Vijayawada">Vijayawada</option>
                                    <option value="Kakinada">Kakinada</option>
                                    <option value="Thirupathi">Thirupathi</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="clear:both; height:10px;">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4" id="txt">
                                <div>Remarks</div>
                                <div class="clr" ng-show="adminForm.Remarks.$error.required">required</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <textarea name="Remarks" id="Remarks" cols="20" rows="10" style="width: 200px" ng-model="user.Remarks" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div style="clear:both; display:block; width:100%; text-align:left;">
                                    <div style="float:left;">
                                        <div style="float:left; margin:2px;">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div>
                                        <button href="img/SendingMail.gif" id="SendButton" name="SendButton" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 298px;" ng-disabled="adminForm.$invalid" ng-click="clear()">Send</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7" id="rightcol">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="moduletable_menu col-md-4" ng-show="showHome">
                    <h3>Home Loans</h3>
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li><a href="#/eligiblehome" id="eligiblehome"><span>Eligibility</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/documenthome" id="documenthome"><span>Documents</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/faqhome" id="faqhome"><span>FAQ'S</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="moduletable_menu col-md-4" ng-show="showMortagage">
                    <h3>Mortagage Loans</h3>
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li><a href="#/eligiblemortagage" id="eligiblemortagage"><span>Eligibility</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/documentmortagage" id="documentmortagage"><span>Documents</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div ng-view>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
            <div id="footer"></div>
    </footer>
</div>
<div id="large"></div>
<div id="background"></div>
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular.min.js.map"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHk7x.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because the nav-bars "z-index" is a higher value than the "background", you need to either decrease the z-index of the nav-bar or increase the z-index of the overlay

The higher the z-index value the higher the layer its on, the highest values will be on top of the lower values.

e.g CSS:

```
#background{
    z-index: 100;
}

.navbar-collapse {
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks Alfie this helps to fix the issue by increasing z-index for background greyout.......

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has a built in `modal` that can do this. It might be easier than writing your own custom JS and CSS.

Docs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals